# MySQL - ordering alphabetically except for one entry?

Tags: mysql

I have to sort a list of categories using MySQL as I am using a CMS that only allows this. Is there a way to sort alphabetically but to return one entry ("Other") at the end of the list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ORDER BY ColumnName = 'Other', ColumnName`

Answer (score 0):

if 'Other' is not present in Table USE

```
(SELECT name FROM categories ORDER BY name)
UNION
(SELECT "Other")
```