# Custom MYSQL Custom Sort Order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a simple media gallery that sorts the albums based on date as seen in the code example. In amongst the albums I have a "Trash" album for deleted media. How do I keep the ORDER BY albums.date DESC but always set the "Trash" album to be the very last in the order? The album is in column "title" and is always called "trash".

Thanks for your help...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT albums.*,photos.path FROM albums LEFT JOIN photos ON albums.albumCover=photos.id WHERE albums.user='$siteUserID' ORDER BY albums.date DESC");
```

Comment: Check out this question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180032/mysql-ordering-alphabetically-except-for-one-entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take advantage of the `CASE` on `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE..
ORDER BY   (CASE 
               WHEN albums.title = 'TRASH'
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END ) ASC, albums.date DESC
```

Comment: @xtiaan in the order by clause, it test the value of the `title` whether is it a `trash` or not, if it is `trash` it sets a virtual value for the row to `1` otherwise `0` and then sorts them in ascending order. after that, it then sorts the `albums.date` in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an `ORDER BY CASE` which assigns a higher number to the `Trash` values, hence sorting them later than others.  Values not `Trash` get a zero, and `Trash` gets a 1. The zeros sort first!

```
SELECT
  albums.*,
  photos.path
FROM 
  albums
  LEFT JOIN photos ON albums.albumCover=photos.id 
WHERE albums.user='$siteUserID' 
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN albums.title = 'Trash' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  /* Then suborder the zeros and ones by date */
  albums.date DESC
```